# Correct HAML for linking an image to another page in my Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Trying to figure out how to use haml "link_to" with Ruby code in order to make an image on a page link to another page on the site. If possible I'd like to keep the nav static and fade the two pages in and out via a "Forward" and "Back" image. Any ideas? Just want to get the linking right first and then can go in and figure out the JQuery. Currently have the code below...

Thanks!!

```
    .pad-bottom50
    %div{:style => "position: absolute; top: 620px; left: 830px;"}
        =link_to (image_tag(@page.photos[1].image_url(:full), :id => "#fade1", :class => "animated") if @page.photos[1].image? 
    .pad-top20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax of link_to is

```
=link_to link_text, link_url, options
```

You missed the link_url. ie. to where the user should be taken when clicking on the image.

Here is a working example

```
=link_to(image_tag("http://goo.gl/FZUI3"), "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyan_Cat", :id => "#fade1", :class => "animated")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the src for the link.
The syntax is:

```
link_to "Link Text", "/path-to-link"
```

To put an image in there:

```
image_tag "path-to-image"
link_to(image_tag("path-to-image"), "/path-to-link")
```

This code will make an image wrapped by a link pointing to /bacon if @page.photos[1].image?

```
link_to(image_tag(image_tag(@page.photos[1].image_url(:full), :id => "#fade1", :class => "animated")), "/bacon", :id => "bacon", :class => "bacon") if @page.photos[1].image?
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Adapting the code you provided gave me a broken image with a link that pointed to the right place, but it ended up working when I changed it to this.

=link_to(image_tag(@page.photos[1].image_url(:full), :id => "#fade1", :class => "animated"), "/page-to-link-to") if @page.photos[1].image?

Answer (score 1):

You should first look at the parameters of a link_to tag . You will get to know about the parameters and what you can do with those parameters .

check this link 
[api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

You can check all paramters of a method avilable in [API Ruby on Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)